# What is "outheroding"?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning-in-context

I have been reading Scott's *Ivanhoe* recently and have come across a word I cannot find a meaning for: *outheroding*. In the novel it appears in a discussion of footwear:

> Fur and gold were not spared in his garments; and the point of his boots, *outheroding* the preposterous fashion of his time, turned up so very far, as to be attached, not to his knees merely but to his very girdle, and effectually prevented him from putting his foot into the stirrup.

A search of the internet produces a reference [here](http://www.fullbooks.com/Biographia-Literaria7.html) where it appears as

> The characters in this act
>   frisk about, here, there, and every where, as teasingly as the Jack o'
>   Lantern-lights which mischievous boys, from across a narrow street,
>   throw with a looking-glass on the faces of their opposite neighbours.
>   Bertram disarmed, *outheroding* Charles de Moor in the Robbers, befaces
>   the collected knights of St. Anselm, (all in complete armour) and so,
>   by pure dint of black looks, he outdares them into passive poltroons.

which doesn't help much in establishing what the word means.

Does anyone know what *outheroding* is?

Comment: In Wiktionary we only have this in the spelling (or hyphenating and capitalizing for the pedants), “out-Herod”: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/out-Herod

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The meaning Scott intended is to *outdo in absurdity* (I came across that unusual definition in an online dictionary, but lost the reference - sorry).

All my dictionaries limit their definition to *outdo in cruelty*, if they even list the word at all. The proverbial saying is **to out-Herod Herod** - which isn't particularly common in the first place, but when it *is* used, that's nearly always the form.

In all Google NGram's vast corpus, **outherod** (or **outHerod**) appears on average less than once a year, and nearly all of those occur as **outHerod Herod** in the actual text (i.e. - explicitly repeating the full saying). NGrams doesn't support searching for **out-herod**, but presumably there would be more results for that if it did.

The expression appears in [this quite old](http://william-shakespeare.classic-literature.co.uk/the-tragedie-of-hamlet/ebook-page-23.asp) text of Shakespeare's Hamlet as **it outHerod's Herod**, but I couldn't say if that's how the Bard himself wrote it. However, I suspect he may have been the first to write it at all.

Note that **out-(someone) (someone)** is a fairly standard way of generating "one-off" expressions like this today. Google returns 130K hits for **out-Bush Bush** and 50K for **out-Blair Blair**, for example. That compares to 20K for the Herod version, just to put it in context.

In my opinion, **out-Herod** (irrespective of hyphenation or capitalisation) isn't really a 'word' at all. It's just a transient lexical element that no more deserves to be in the dictionary than **out-Obama** (which gets over 230K Google hits, by the way).

I'm no biblical scholar, but I don't think Herod has any particular reputation for extravagance or absurdity. As far as I know, extreme cruelty as exemplified by the [Massacre of the Innocents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massacre_of_the_Innocents)was his proverbial quality. So I think Scott's usage was grammatically, typographically and semantically  perverse, to say the least.

Comment: so presumably the pronunciation is out - hair' - owe - ding as opposed to ow' - the - row - ding?

Comment: @Mitch: Absolutely. Some of the entries I leafed though in NGram actually transcribed it as outHerod, which makes that a bit clearer.

Answer (score 5):

"outheroding" is a present participle form of "outherod".

Here is the definition for ["outherod"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/outherod).

> to outdo in extravagance, violence, or excess: His cruelty out-Herods Herod.

Answer (score 2):

[outheroding](http://www.memidex.com/outheroding) [present participle form of outherod] means:

```
    "To surpass someone in cruelty or evil".
```

Answer (score 1):

refers to the figure of biblical Herod, who allegedly had the innocent babies slaughtered. In popular medieval churchplays often presented by actors in an exaggerated way as pure evil. That is what Hamlet refers to when he talks to a troup of actors he asks to stage the murder of his father, meaning that to achieve the effect wished for (mirroring his horrible deed to his uncle) they have to act in a realistic way.